# What's the story with setTextColor's param being an int but being ok with 8 digit hex values?

Tags: java, android, hex

I'm really confused by the fact that `TextView.setTextColor(int)` is perfectly ok with
0xFFFFFFFF as an input value
but is not ok with the decimal equivalent of
4294967295

Now, I totally understand why that second value is totally out of range for an int. My question is why the hex value is NOT out of range!

The reason I ask is that I have a situation where I'm reading hex values from a text file that I need to use at runtime to set the colors of various text fields in the app.

I'm running into a wall trying the various string to int methods in Java (`Long.parseLong`, et al), but none of them are doing the trick.

What's the right way to convert a string hex value into something that setTextColor will be happy with and will interpret correctly?

Comment: 0xFFFFFFFF as integer is -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of different rules in the JLS for different forms of [Integer Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)

"It is a compile-time error if a decimal literal of type int is larger than 2147483648 (231), or if the decimal literal 2147483648 appears anywhere other than as the operand of the unary minus operator (§15.15.4)."

"It is a compile-time error if a hexadecimal, octal, or binary int literal does not fit in 32 bits."

A hex, octal, or binary literal can be the 2's complement representation of a negative number.

Comment: thanks... as a follow up to my own question, which I figured out, the string representation of the value that you pass into parseLong (or parseInt for that matter) must not have a leading `0x`. It should just be the alphanum value along with the radix as in parseInt("FF333333",16). So you need to manually strip the 0x from the front of the string first.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [`Color`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) class will help :

> Colors are represented as packed ints, made up of 4 bytes: alpha, red,
>   green, blue. The values are unpremultiplied, meaning any transparency
>   is stored solely in the alpha component, and not in the color
>   components. The components are stored as follows (alpha << 24) | (red
>   << 16) | (green << 8) | blue. Each component ranges between 0..255
>   with 0 meaning no contribution for that component, and 255 meaning
>   100% contribution. Thus opaque-black would be 0xFF000000 (100% opaque
>   but no contributions from red, green, or blue), and opaque-white would
>   be 0xFFFFFFFF

Comment: I understand how colors work and how they're represented. What I don't understand is how the method differentiates between a hex value and a dec value and why it isn't happy accepting either (of equal size).  Is it a signed/unsigned issue of some sort?